# How to get the image size of an image and use it to name the image

Tags: python, json, image, image-processing, download

I need to download an image from the internet and name it after its dimensions, like 1920 x 1080.
I managed to download the images to my local computer, but I am not sure how to get the image dimensions before I download the image.
I was thinking maybe I could download the image, use PIL to get the image dimensions, redownload the image, and delete the old one, but this would take much longer.

```
for landcover in data['results']:
  siteId = landcover['siteId']
  measuredDate = landcover['measuredDate']
  latitude = landcover['latitude']
  longitude = landcover['longitude']
  protocol = landcover['protocol']
  DownURL = landcover['data']['landcoversDownwardPhotoUrl']
  EastURL = landcover['data']['landcoversEastPhotoUrl']

  r = requests.get(EastURL)
  with open('GLOBEObserver_' + str(userid) + '_' + str(siteId) + '_' + protocol + '_' + str(latitude) + '_' + str(longitude) + '_' + str(measuredDate) + '_' + str(width) + '_' + str(height) + 'East.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: You can not get the image dimensions direct.But it is not necessary to redownload and delete the same picture.May `BytesIO` can solve your issue? Load image from BytesIO to get the image dimensions and wirte the data of the BytesIO to a file will not be very longer.

Comment: Delete and re-download? Why not just rename the file you already have?

Comment: This isn't the full code, but there will be thousands of files that I need to rename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the steps:

1. Get the bytes of images.
2. Use `PIL` to convert it(`bytes`) to a `PIL.Image`(object).
3. Get the size of the object.
4. Save the object locally

simple example:

```
import requests
import io
import PIL

response = requests.get(url) # make sure it is the url of the image
image_bytes = response.content

# convert the bytes to image
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
width, height = image.size
# save it
image.save(f"{width}x{height}.jpg")
```

Comment: When I tried to run the code, I got the following error: image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined

Comment: I just solved it. Instead "import PIL" I used "import PIL.Image as Image." Thank you for your help!!!!